# Struts 2 Template not found

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, themes, freemarker

I created a new theme template for Struts 2.

So I placed following code into my `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="mynew" />
```

Where is this template directory, so that I can put the new theme into it. I tried many locations and none of them worked.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template /template/mynew/actionerror.ftl not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts 2 would first look for a tag's template in `webroot/template/theme` name. And if it didn't find the template there it will use the default template that is a part of the Struts 2 core jar. You can learn more about this feature in [Template Loading](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/template-loading.html).

> Template directory can be selected using several different rules, in this order:
>
> - The `templateDir` attribute on the specific tag
> - The page-scoped attribute named `templateDir`
> - The request-scoped attribute named `templateDir`
> - The session-scoped attribute named `templateDir`
> - The application-scoped attribute named templateDir
> - The `struts.ui.templateDir` property in `struts.properties` (defaults to template)

Answer (score 0):

The main clue in Roman C's answer for placing the templates in the correct folder is that he mentions **webroot**. I haven't seen this anywhere else. So based on that here is a working example.

My project is in an EAR file which looks like this inside:

- my_project_ejb.jar
- my_project.war
- lib folder with required jars

To make templates work, there should be a "template" (or whatever else you configure it) folder in your WAR file at the top level. Within that, create a folder with the name of your theme.

Since my project is built with Maven, my FTL files are in `my_web_project/src/main/webapp/template_dir_name/theme_name/my_field_template.ftl`

I hope this is useful for someone. Took me a while to figure it out.